# What's the correct OR condition for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

Is this correct for an OR condition in jQuery?

```
$('a.clickNews' || '#footer p a:eq(2)').click(function(){
   //statement
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: It's not "either-or", it's "element a **and** element b" you want to select.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that will only select `'a.clickNews'`.  You need to use a comma to separate them:

```
$('a.clickNews, #footer p a:eq(2)').click(function(){
   //statement
});
```

See [Multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) in the API.